# MySQL queries waiting for other queries to finish

Tags: mysql, database, multithreading, locking, innodb

We have 30-40 different projects in Python and PHP that update, insert and select more than 1 million rows of data in MySQL DB every day.

Currently we use InnoDB Engine for our tables.

The problem: we have peaks in MySQL when almost all projects are working and lots of queries are processing in DB. There are main queries that are very important to finish ASAP (high priority) and queries that can wait for finish of main queries (less priority).
But as they go to MySQL concurrent it causes main queries to wait finishing of less priority queries.

Questions:

1. Is there any possibility to release all lock in tables before executing main queries (so they can finish ASAP)? or create locks if it help?
2. Can we pause the less priority queries execution when start execution main queries automatically?
3. Can use HIGH_PRIORITY and LOW_PRIORITY in queries help?
4. Are there some configurations in MySQL that can help?
5. Can changing tables to MyISAM or other DB engine help?

Let me know your thoughts and ideas.

Comment: This is a server tuning problem and you might have more luck over at [the DBA site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) as it probably pertains to server configuration and not application code. Whatever your problem MyISAM is not your answer.

Comment: Please show us some of the queries at the peak, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

1. No.  You might try upgrading to MySQL 5.7 as it allows parallel replication within tables if the transactions do not interfere with each other.
2. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html about how LOW PRIORITY has no effect.
3. See #2.
4. It would probably be better to look how you are doing your locking in your application - -are you locking rows up, making changes, unlock quickly or does the code do this in a leisurely fashion?
5. MyISAM locks at the table level not the row level and MyISAM does not support transactions (Which is probably why you are locking records).

Answer (score 0):

it's hard giving a definitive answer without the locking queries.
If you could add them it will be more useful.
Several things you can look into:
Look for locking statements such as "select for update", "insert on conflict update" etc...
-many times it's better to catch an exception on the application side then let the db do extra work.

the read concurrency: it could be that "read-committed " is enough for you and it takes less locks.

If you have replication- dedicate instances according to usage (e.g. Critical only server)

Regards
Jony

Answer (score 0):

Look through your high priority queries and ensure they are well written and have/use appropriate indexes.

Look at other queries using the same tables as the high priority queries and ensure their optimization the same way.

With better queries/index less CPU/RAM are used, and there will be less implicit locks happening on rows maximising the change that all queries will be quick.

Query and tuning help on the DBA site however more information will be needed.